# Creating a task in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a CRON task for daily report. I need guidance where to create my class in my project (in which folder). How to instantiate an object from rails console for the same class. Will that class inherit application controller? I would also like to know since i will be querying my database so would my models be directly accessible in this file or somehow i have to include them like we do in django?

I have created a class /lib/tasks/daily_report.rb. But i am unable to understand how will i use that file to create a task.

```
module Reports
    class Report
        class << self
            def collect_data
                row_data = []
                headers = ["Mobile", "Buildings", "Owners", "Tenants", "Members", "Total People"]
                row_data.push(*headers)

                puts "in side collect data"
                date = Date.today.to_s

                mobile = ["mobiles"]

                for i in mobile do
                    row = []
                    row << i

                    build_count   = Buildings.where(created_at: date, added_by: i).count
                    row << build_count
                    puts "build_count"

                    owners_count  = Residents.where(created_at: date, added_by: i, role: "owner").count
                    row << owners_count
                    puts "owners_count"
                    tenants_count = Residents.where(created_at: date, added_by: i, role: "tenant").count
                    row << tenants_count

                    members_count = MemeberRelations.where(created_at: date, added_by: i).count
                    row <<  members_count

                    total_people  = owners_count + tenants_count + members_count
                    row << total_people

                    row_data << row
                end
                puts row_data
                return row_data
            end

            def generate_csv()
                puts "walk away"
                row_data = self.collect_data
                CSV.open('/home/rajdeep/police-api/daily_report.csv', 'w') do |csv|
                    row_data.each { |ar| csv << ar }
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: If this method is inside your model them you can call directly the model form tasks,

Comment: where do you want to deploy the app? Some cloud hoster provide a "scheduler" or "crontab". From there you could call a rake-task https://dev.to/vinistock/customizing-rails-rake-tasks-3bg5

Comment: @SimonFranzen Hi i am deploying it on aws but i was testing locally first.

Comment: @AbhishekAravindan Hi i have created a script to run in my task in /project/scripts.
How can i make database queries in that file.

Comment: You should define your task in /lib/tasks/sometask.rake

Comment: You can query database from the rake tasks.

Comment: @AbhishekAravindan i have defined my task in /lib/tasks/my_task.rake.
I want this task to run a script file defined in project/scripts/script.rb .
The script.rb file is the above mentioned file that has database queries. I want to know that can i make database query without importing including models?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to manage cron tasks from Rails, try [`whenever` gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever).

Add it to your Gemfile,

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'whenever', require: false
```

Run initialize task from root of your app

```
$ bundle exec wheneverize .
```

> This will create an initial config/schedule.rb file for you (as long
>   as the config folder is already present in your project)

(from the gem docs).

After that in `config/schedule.rb` set proper parameters of call time. For example

**config/schedule.rb**

```
every :hour do # Many shortcuts available: :hour, :day, :month, :year, :reboot
  runner "Report.generate_csv"
end
```

More syntax options of `schedule.rb` [here](https://github.com/javan/whenever#example-schedulerb-file)

**UPDATE AFTER COMMENTS**

Hope, you're under Rails context yet. Create file in `public` folder at application root path.

```
result_file = "#{Rails.root}/public/cards-excluded.csv"
CSV.open(result_file, 'w') do |csv|
  row_data.each { |ar| csv << ar }
end
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE LATER**

Okay, although this is not relevant to the original question, let's try to solve your problem.

We'll proceed from what you have Rails application, not custom Ruby library.

First, create module at `your_rals_app/lib/reports.rb` file

```
module Reports
  class Report
    class << self
      def collect_data
        # your current code and line below, explicit return
        return row_data
      end

      def generate_csv
        row_data = collect_data # btw unnecessary assignment
        CSV.open('/home/rajdeep/police-api/daily_report.csv', 'w') do |csv|
          row_data.each { |ar| csv << ar }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Second, make sure, that you have lib files at autoload path. Check it in you `config/application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/*)
```

Thirdly, use `Reports` module such way (`>` means that you're at rails console, `rails c`)

```
> Reports::Report.generate_csv
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202265/discussion-on-answer-by-cnnr-creating-a-task-in-ruby-on-rails).